# What does Golang patent mean

Tags: patent-infringement

What does the patent grant for Golang mean? Can I use Golan for whatever I want (like the BSD license implies) or does it limit my use of Golang in any way?

Here is the text of the patent:
https://golang.org/PATENTS?m=text

Comment: This may be off topic in that it is more about licensing than patents. Perhaps post on the Law SE site?

Comment: @EricShain Is licensing in relation to patents really off topic?  I'm also wondering why the linked text doesn't reference the patent for which rights are being granted, nor does the base url: https://golang.org/

Comment: @DukeZhou I’m not a moderator, but I think the Law SE site might be a more productive site for this question.

Comment: The linked text doesn't reference any particular patent, but does make pretty clear that the user is free from infringement so long as they don't change the language such that it infringes on someone else's patent.

Comment: The answer is not correct. It apples to  patents that Google itself owns that are embodied in Google's GO software.

Answer (score 1):

In the license for the GO software Google grants a licenses to the patents that *Google owns* regarding the GO software.

exerpt

> here such license applies only to those patent
>    claims, both currently owned or controlled by Google and acquired in the future, licensable by Google that are necessarily infringed by this implementation of Go.

Answer (score -2):

Go is an [open-source](https://holi-2020.com) programming language that makes it easy to build simple, reliable, and efficient software. And Golang is Go Language. If someone builds software using Golang and registers it as Patent, then it is said as Golang Patent.

Comment: IMO, you need to amend your link ('open-source'). It took me to https://holi-2020.com/page/2/ . Which, to me, is not related to your disclosure. Perhaps you intended to link something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language). It will be appreciated, if reference link to any 'Golang patent' is cited.

Comment: I don’t think this really answers the question. At all.